# restart program upon file not being modified

Tags: windows, restart

I cant find a bat file which will restart a program when a telegram file is not modified for lets say 2 minutes or so? telegram.session. a trade copier program. Like if telegram.session is not modified for 2 minutes restart tradecopier.exe. the tradecopier.exe will be running during this as well as telegram

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: I tried searching for a code on here. does someone already have a similer code to do this? for a bat file

Comment: This site is for writing code, not for finding code.